# CURLOPT_NOBODY option returns unexpected HTTP code 200 on non-existing file

Tags: php, apache, http, curl

I have a server, called `install64-7` in this example which I will access to check for the existance of a zip file, which is not on server. The following PHP code returns the HTTP returncode `200` even if the zip file does not exist on the server `install64-7`.

```
$srcPath = "http://install64-7/TestApp.zip";
$ch = curl_init( $srcPath );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
curl_exec( $ch );
$retcode = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
curl_close( $ch );
unset( $ch );
var_dump($retcode);
exit;
```

[image]

In case I remove the option `CURLOPT_NOBODY`, the request gives a `404`! see screenshot for second request

```
$srcPath = "http://install64-7/TestApp.zip";
$ch = curl_init( $srcPath );
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
curl_exec( $ch );
$retcode = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
curl_close( $ch );
unset( $ch );
var_dump($retcode);
exit;
```

[image]

How is this possible, what am I missing? What is this sorcery about the option `CURLOPT_NOBODY`?
Thank you for any help

Comment: Can you post the actual HTTP traffic please (request + response headers).

Comment: added request+response headers

Comment: Have you tried this  on a browser ? firefox + addon live http headers. Check if the servers returns 200 on 404's.   https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/

Comment: yeah these headers are from firebug in firefox... it does say status 200 for a 404. häh - now I'm getting really confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CURLOPT_NOBODY set to TRUE makes a HTTP HEAD request, as compared to the "normal" HTTP GET.

If you get a different repsonse code because of that it is simply because the server decides to respond differently - although it shouldn't according to the HTTP spec.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Well, I'm using the standard debian package for apache2 (2.2.22-13+deb7u1). So what could be different in the apache settings to have this unspecified behaviour happening?

Comment: Could avoid this problem for a while... now I'm facing this issue again. I have checked my apache settings, they have not been changed since installation. Any suggestions why apache reacts like that - whatever the HTTP spec sais, this seems to be apache standard behaviour :(

Comment: oh found it today, actually another non-default module was also in place, which was specified to do this.