# PHP Curl Check 404 : Always return HTTPCODE 200 OK

Tags: php, curl, nginx, http-status-code-404

I am trying to fix links on a website. I have to check for 404 for all links on a page. I am using php curl to check response http code. But strangely it always return 200 OK.

Here is my code for `is_404()`,

```
$curl = curl_init($url);

//don't fetch the actual page, you only want to check the connection is ok
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

//do request
$result = curl_exec($curl);

$ret = true;

//if request did not fail
if ($result !== false) {
    //if request was ok, check response code
    $statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  

    if ($statusCode == 200) {
        $ret = false;   
    }
}

curl_close($curl);

return $ret;
```

I always return 200 OK even on a page where there is 404 page is displaying. Server is handling all 404 with proper page.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the 404 page is also returning status code 404?

Comment: This might explain the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248822/curlopt-nobody-option-returns-unexpected-http-code-200-on-non-existing-file

Comment: All 404 has pages which show that you have enter wrong url. All returns 200 OK response. I may need to set 404 http code header for that page i think.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue until i understand it was because of multiple failover ip in my network configuration

```
host A ( failover ip1,failover  ip2 )

host B ( failover ip1,failover  ip2 )
```

curl create false positive on host B because it resolve by default the IP, even if the failover point to host A, the call was in local

perhaps it s the same on your configuration ?

a simple workaround which fix my problem:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "eth0");
```